# Handling 32 byte integer in the hex format

Tags: integer, hex, byte

I have a 32-byte integer in the hex format, example:
`0xAB CD 12 34 AB CD 12 34 AB CD 12 34 AB CD 12 34 AB CD 12 34 AB CD 12 34 AB CD 12
34 AB CD 12 34`

How do I display it to base 2 notation? I don't fully understand how to implement an int in the given format.

Comment: Hex is just one way of displaying a numeric value.  You could just as easily display it as decimal (base 10), octal (base 8) or any base you choose.  If that number is stored in a device that uses binary memory, it already is base 2, so your question is unclear.  Do you simply want to display its value in binary notation?

Comment: @CareyGregory: Yes, I want to display its base-2 equivalent.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @arshajii: I basically use Java. But, I just want its base-2 notation as I'm working on an assembly project. Hence, I don't want to use any predefined libraries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is C++, but it should give you the idea.

```
unsigned char bytes[32] = { 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34 };

for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    unsigned char byte = bytes[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%u", (byte & 0x80) >> 7);
        byte <<= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, at the end, I will have 256 `0`s and `1`s?

Comment: @PalakArora - Yes.  32 bytes x 8 bits = 256.

Answer (score 0):

Take each digit of the hexadecimal number and convert it into a binary (base-2) number using a hash table, i.e. A will become 1010b. The binary number should have zeroes added on the left so that it is 4 characters, i.e. it should be "11", *not* "0011". You could use an array but you will have to take the ordinal of the character and if it is equal or below 57, then subtract 48 (so that "9", ordinal 57 will become the integer 9). Similarly, lower values will become the corresponding integer. But "A" is at ordinal 65, so if the ordinal is above or equal to 65, then subtract 50, so that "A" becomes the integer 10. Your array will be `"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "100", ...`, so that when any integer is indexed, the corresponding binary (base-2) representation will be returned.

Comment: So the base-2 number (in the above case) will have 256 characters consisting of `0`s and `1`s?

Comment: @PalakArora Yup, each digit in hexadecimal has 16 possible values, so the there'll be 4 binary digits for each hexadecimal digit, and thus the binary representation will use 256 characters. You might want to read this Simple Wikipedia entry: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to know how to convert hex to binary.

If you're using Windows (7), just open the calculator, set the view to programmer, select "Hex", type in your number, then select "bin" - or just watch the display update.

If you're using *ix, run `bc`, and type `ibase=16`, `obase=2`, then just type your number and hit enter.

In general, you ***really*** should know what hex and binary mean.  If you can't convert from one to the other for the basic values of 0-15, you've missed the most core parts of being a programmer.  It's important to understand.  Binary - a numerical system on which almost all digital logic is based - is made of only 0s and 1s.  Hex is effectively just a shorthand for binary.  Instead of storing base2, you store base16.  Since 16 = 2^4, you can condense 4 bits into one hex code.

```
0x0 = 0000 = 0
0x1 = 0001 = 1
0x2 = 0010 = 2
0x3 = 0011 = 3
0x4 = 0100 = 4
0x5 = 0101 = 5
0x6 = 0110 = 6
0x7 = 0111 = 7
0x8 = 1000 = 8
0x9 = 1001 = 9
0xA = 1010 = 10
0xB = 1011 = 11
0xC = 1100 = 12
0xD = 1101 = 13
0xE = 1110 = 14
0xF = 1111 = 15
```